# Como tirar as margens do layout do Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Quero retirar aquelas margens`azul` para minha linha `verde` pegar o `layout` todo e não ficar com nenhuma margem, mas sem retirar os `padding` do `RelativeLayout`

É a ActionBar `vermelho` que está com um `margim bottom` ou a minha View `verde` que está com um `margin top`?

[image: Imagem]

**<sub>layout.xml</sub>**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ACD10A"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Exception, em geral a `ActionBar` não interfere no layout do conteúdo. Porque modifica seu layout para tirar a `View` de dentro do `RelativeLayout`, englobando em um `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @Wakim pode dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tirar o efeito do padding da `View` que da o efeito de linha sugiro englobar o seu layout em um `LinearLayout` e colocar o `RelativeLayout` abaixo da `View`. Dessa maneira:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="#ACD10A" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <!-- Restante do layout -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Algumas considerações:

1. O uso do `layout_height="0dp"` e `layout_weight="1"` força que o `RelativeLayout` ocupe todo o espaço restante, a `View` que emula uma linha irá ocupar `1dp` e o `RelativeLayout` o restante.